C++ macro for defining enums and helper function to convert from int to that enum
I would like to create a macro to define an enum and also create a helper function that converts an int to that enum and returns std::nullopt if there is no enum with the passed value.
I would like to be able to create an enum like such:
SOME_MACRO(ENUM_NAME, 
    (foo, 1),
    (bar, 5), 
)

(Note that the values of the enum are not sequential).
I have to create a lot of enums like this so I would like to only have one definition of each enum where I need to change if the values change.
Here is the closest I have gotten:
#define DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_CONVERSION(EnumName, ENUM_LIST)                         \
    enum class EnumName {                                                        \
        ENUM_LIST(ENUM_ENTRY)                                                    \
    };                                                                           \
                                                                                 \
    std::optional<EnumName> intTo##EnumName(int value) {                         \
        switch (value) {                                                         \
            ENUM_LIST(ENUM_CASE)                                                 \
            default:                                                             \
                return std::nullopt;                                             \
        }                                                                        \
    }

// Helper macros for enum definition and switch cases
#define ENUM_ENTRY(name, value) name = value,
#define ENUM_CASE(name, value) case value: return EnumName::name;

// Define the list of enum values
#define VALUE_LIST(X)                                                        \
    X(value1, 0)                                                       \
    X(value2, 1)

// Correct usage of the macro to define the enum and the conversion function
DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_CONVERSION(Value, VALUE_LIST)

But in #define ENUM_CASE(name, value) case value: return EnumName::name; EnumName is not getting replaced to the actual name.
NOTE: I tried using the using enum EnumName keyword but I can only use c++17, not c++20.
EDIT: The macro I posted is the closest I got, there is no need to build upon it if there is a better way to do it.

wouldnt a std::unordered_map<int,std::string> do the same (and more) with much less effort ?

Maybe you need the 3rd argument to underlying macros like #define ENUM_ENTRY(EnumName, name, value), #define ENUM_CASE(EnumName, name, value)` and pass it accordingly

@463035818_is_not_an_ai that would work but this is an embedded environment and that would probably be too much overhead... Something like a switch case and an enum is much simpler

@Roconx A std::flat_map inspired thing might do the trick perhaps?

@AlexeyS.Larionov That would work but it is not clean at all as #define VALUE_LIST(X)                                                        \     X(value1, 0)                                                       \     X(value2, 1) would also need that third argument. Unless I am missing something

@TedLyngmo I belive std::flat_map is c++23 and above, and I can only use up to c++17. Also, this is an embedded environment so I don't think it would be the best option...

I think the problem is that EnumName expands to Value before EMUM_CASE is expanded. A less convoluted use of X macros would probably solve this. You could for example include the enum name as part of the X macro list indeed (a 3rd parameter item).

@Lundin I could do that but that would be too much unnecessary repetition and not clean at all.

Can you leverage magic enum?

@Eljay Looks pretty interesting, I'll take a look!

Instead of a macro, why not just use python or something to generate the appropriate headers at configure/build time?  No need to mess with macros at all.

What you will be told at a code review is to think of ways to make this code simpler and more readable. And stop thinking of ways to make it even more complex - it's already a hot X macro mess. Particularly for C++ where you can offload some of this to template, a luxury you wouldn't have in the equivalent C code. Also it is really weird that the helper function isn't included in the class, removing the need to name it separately. Use OO design.

Also this is a good example for using LUT or maybe some constexpr. Not switch.

@Roconx Yes, flat_map is C++23, but making a flat_map inspired container shouldn't be that hard - and I don't think it's need much more memory than your macros.

@StephenNewell Integrating python into the build process is way more complicated than writing a macro, IMO.

Conversion from int to name in C-style enum is unreliable by definition, as multiple entries can share same numeric value. Enums are nothing more than a tool to make code more readable. They're not meant to be a part of the program. I think you're trying to force enums into doing things they're not supposed to to. If you have experience in other languages, with first-class enums, your experience is misleading you. Enum in Java vs enum in C++ is like English "kinder" and German "kinder" - same word, different meaning.

@Agent_L The conversion function should take an argument of the enum class type, not int as it does now.

@TedLyngmo Type is taken as generic parameter. I'm talking about case enum Foo { eeny=1, meeny=1, miny=1, mo=1}; - so the question "what does 1 mean?" has multiple correct answers.

@Agent_L Yeah, 1 doesn't have a meaning in the enum class.  Only the name :)

The simple way to fix this is to add using ThisEnum = EnumName; to the intTo##EnumName(), and use that in ENUM_CASE instead of EnumName.
But I wouldn't stop here. You can make a better call syntax for this macro, that doesn't require defining helper macros for every enum:
DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_CONVERSION( Value,
    (value1, 0)
    (value2, 1)
)

#define DEFINE_ENUM_WITH_CONVERSION(EnumName, Elems) \
    enum class EnumName \
    { \
        END( ENUM_LIST_A Elems ) \
    }; \
    \
    std::optional<EnumName> intTo##EnumName(int value) \
    { \
        using ThisEnum = EnumName; \
        switch (value) \
        { \
            END( ENUM_CASE_A Elems ) \
            default: \
                return std::nullopt; \
        } \
    }

#define END(...) END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define ENUM_LIST_A(name, ...) name = __VA_ARGS__, ENUM_LIST_B
#define ENUM_LIST_B(name, ...) name = __VA_ARGS__, ENUM_LIST_A
#define ENUM_LIST_A_END
#define ENUM_LIST_B_END

#define ENUM_CASE_A(name, ...) case __VA_ARGS__: return ThisEnum::name; ENUM_CASE_B
#define ENUM_CASE_B(name, ...) case __VA_ARGS__: return ThisEnum::name; ENUM_CASE_A
#define ENUM_CASE_A_END
#define ENUM_CASE_B_END

And for the general problem of using external parameters in a preprocessor loop (which we avoided here with the using), you can use something like this library of mine: https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for

This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!
